# PHP Array Sorting And Getting Max Values from a Matrix

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm hoping there's an easy way to do this without tons and tons of loops.

I have a matrix in the following manner:

```
    Weight1 Weight2 Weight3 .... WeightN
Jan    1       3       5            4
Feb    10      12      15          11
Mar    5       7       4            3
Apr    10      15      7            3
```

Assuming the following array:

```
$arrayMonths = array(
       'jan' => array(1, 3, 5,4)
       'feb' => array(10,12,15,11)
       'mar' => array(5, 7, 4, 3)
       'apr' => array(10,15,7,3)
    );
```

What is the best way for me to get the the max for each row:
jan = 5
feb = 15
mar = 7
apr = 15

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the perfect algorithm:  Basically use a recursive function which goes through all permutations.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arrayMonths as $month => $array) {
    // store the max of each month for later
    // $max['jan'] = 5
    $max[$month] = max($array);

    // or print it out
    echo $month. ' => '. max($array);
}
```

From the [max() PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

If you need to go further with sorting you can check out here for more information
[PHP Array Sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function:

```
foreach($arrayMonths as $month => $row)
{
    echo $month . ": " . max($row) . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function getMax( $v, $k ) {
    global $arrayMonths;

    $arrayMonths[ 'max' ][$k] = max($v);
}

$arrayMonths = array(
   'jan' => array(1, 3, 5,4),
   'feb' => array(10,12,15,11),
   'mar' => array(5, 7, 4, 3),
   'apr' => array(10,15,7,3)
);

array_walk( $arrayMonths, 'getMax' );

// Now $arrayMonths['max'] will contain all max values for each key
?>
```

Hope this helps.